# Releasing self-blocking references in Java

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

This is a rather common case: class Team contains a list of all its Member instances while a Member refers to its Team. The Java code looks something like this:

```
public class Team {
    private String name;
    private List<Member> members;

    public Team(final String name, final String... memberNames) {
        this.name = name;

        members = new LinkedList<>();
        for (String memberName : memberNames) 
            members.add(new Member(memberName, this));
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + ": " + members;
    }

}

class Member {
    private String name;
    private Team team;

    public Member(final String name, Team team) {
        this.name = name;
        this.team = team;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + " of " + team.getName();
    }

}
```

Consider also a function `test` which creates a `Team` instance and terminates.

```
public static void test() {
    Team team = new Team("Family", 
        "William",  "Kate", "George");

    System.out.print(team);
}
```

According to common sense, after function test terminates, the `team` object and all its `Member` instances should be released. However the reference count of `team` is non-zero, since all `Member`-s refer to it, while each `Member` cannot be released, because `team` is holding it.

Some languages provide so called "weak references" (not increasing reference count, but set to null automatically when referred object is released) to cope with this problem, but Java doesn't have anything like that.

I can imagine a GC engine that identifies a "closed" group of objects which refer to each other, but have no external references, and such a group can be released. But is JVM is guaranteed to be that smart?  I haven't found any Java document to discuss this issue, so every time I have to create this sort of a structure I am worried. I am especially interested in Dalvik VM.

Comment: There is no reference count. Java GC is specified to work via reachability. It can therefore collect cycles with no difficulty.

Comment: It if is already asked, can you provide a link to it?

Comment: @cyanide It's at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Garbage collection in Java works not by counting references, but by starting at the objects that are directly accessible: on the stack, in static fields, and permanently accessible objects such as classes; it then finds every object referenced by those objects, and so on, and marks all objects that no chain of references could access as garbage. Therefore, it will always release cyclically referential garbage, with no need to use a `WeakReference`.